# Android MediaRecorder Crashes

Tags: java, android, camera, mediarecorder

UPDATED:

Ok, after a few days of testing and debugging... I GOT IT TO WORK, but not the way I want.

The reason it crashed previously was because of "reorientation" of the camera during lockscreen, apparently, that crashes often.

Once I forced it to use landscape mode, it works. However, I don't want it to use landscape mode; I want it to work in portrait mode.

The code is taken directly from Android Studio's sample (Media -> MediaRecorder). The sample had the code working in landscape mode, and I can't figure how to get it to use portrait mode so I can avoid re-orientation and thus avoid the crashes?

There's nothing in the onPause, onResume code and the stacktrace pointed toward this method being called.

Easy Reproduce:

1) Use Android Studio to get the MediaRecord Sample app
2) In the manifest, change, android:screenOrientation="landscape"> to Portrait.
3) The App won't launch now.

I added mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90), same issue.

#### Code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_preview)
    mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultCameraInstance();

    // We need to make sure that our preview and recording video size are supported by the
    // camera. Query camera to find all the sizes and choose the optimal size given the
    // dimensions of our preview surface.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes,
            mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight());

    // Use the same size for recording profile.
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
    profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;

    // likewise for the camera object itself.
    parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    try {
            // Requires API level 11+, For backward compatibility use {@link setPreviewDisplay}
            // with {@link SurfaceView}
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (configure_preview)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
            CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    // END_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
            CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).getPath() }, new String[] { "video/mp4" }, null);
    // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Logs:

```
06-27 02:18:08.244  25734-25752/com.watchdawg.watchdawg E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -22
06-27 02:18:08.253  25734-25752/com.watchdawg.watchdawg E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.watchdawg.watchdawg, PID: 25734
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at com.watchdawg.watchdawg.RecordActivity$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(RecordActivity.java:276)
at com.watchdawg.watchdawg.RecordActivity$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(RecordActivity.java:267)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Should I release the camera and mediaRecorder onPause or onStop?

Is this even the right issue? I might not have identified it properly,

Comment: Hey Dear I am not receving any error with executing https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder this Demo in Android Studio What is the steps or when you got error ?

Comment: Please reply if you want to solve it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want your app to run in the background?

Comment: When I launch normally, it works. Even when I launch the app from keylock, it works fine since I have the SHOW_WHEN_LOCK flag set onAttachedToWindow(), but when the activity is called from an intent from receiver, it bugs out. The receiver is triggered by button press event.

So when the button is pressed, I can see the App flashes in the background of my keyguard for a second, then it fades away. When I unlock the phone, I get the crashed message.

Now the App does work normally on top of the keyguard because if I simply launch the App, it works from keyguard just fine.

Comment: So my question is really...

Is there any different in launching a Default Activity with launcher vs calling it via an context.startActivity(intent) ?

Comment: You should post your onPause and onResume code too

Comment: My onPause and onResume codes are empty. I isolated the issue, it was screen re-orientation during lockscreen, that crashed the app. Apparently, that can't be fixed BUT I can make the app NOT re-orient itself by matching my phone's default orientation with it. This is not ideal, so I rather figure out how to stop the Activity from re-orientating (my default is portrait, so I need the app to accept portrait mode)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever the application is removed from the recent task list, process will not be cleaned up completely, it is just that the UI will be cleaned up. So it is app responsibility to cleanup the resource held by your activity or app. Hence, you need to override **onTaskRemoved()** method in your **service(Android service) component** and perform cleanup(releasing mediaplayer instance etc).

Comment: He's not actually running it in a service though.

Comment: I agree, now i am recommending him to use a service and perform clean up if user swipes the application from recents.

Comment: It's an activity, not a service... I checked my cleanup and it works fine because I disengaged the lockscreen and abused my app launch in different ways and closing it in different ways... Never crashed. It just doesn't launch from startActivity(intent) through a screen-on receiver from lockscreen.

Comment: My onPause and onResume codes are empty. I isolated the issue, it was screen re-orientation during lockscreen, that crashed the app. Apparently, that can't be fixed BUT I can make the app NOT re-orient itself by matching my phone's default orientation with it. This is not ideal, so I rather figure out how to stop the Activity from re-orientating (my default is portrait, so I need the app to accept portrait mode)

Answer (score -1):

try this way:

```
 mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720,480);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mPreview.setRotation(90);
```

instead of mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
hope it works!